# Layout issue with Firefox under Windows 11

Tags: html, css, firefox, media-queries

I have an issue with styling rules on different devices...

In my css rules I am using media queries to adjust the layout to different devices. Works fine so far on different devices I tested on. With one strange exception: Firefox on Windows 11.

Here are the media queries I am using, inside those queries I have a definition that defines `float` for two containers. There is more, obviously, this is stripped down:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) { ... }
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) { 
  .wrapper {
    &.album-list {
      .sidebar {
        width: 30%;
        float: right;
      }
      .content {
        width: 70%;
        float: left;
      }
    }
    &.album {
      .sidebar {
        width: 60%;
        float: left;
      }
      .content {
        width: 40%;
        float: right;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am sure that this is a media query issue, since when I check in the development console of that browser, it does not show *any* of the style rules defined in those media query blocks. Firefox just ignores those. Maybe because it decides that they do not apply, though I fail to understand *why* that should be the case.

I cannot believe that Firefox under Windows 11 does not have valid support for such media queries ...

My question: what am I missing here? Why is the layout working on all devices, also on Chrome under Windows11, but not with Firefox and *only* under Windows11?

Update:

It seems that this is not a general issue. I tried other systems running Windows 11 and Firefox and those behaved fine, as expected. So it appears to be something special on that system where I observe the issue. Anyone got an idea for me what the issue might be with that system?